# How to ignore doubled doublequotes in csv files

Tags: python, csv

I have a malformed csv file which looks like

```
"header_1"; "header_2"
"abc"; "def"
"ghi"; ""jkl""
```

When I use my reader just as this:

```
reader = csv.reader(csv_file, delimiter=";", quotechar='\"', doublequote=True)
```

the code leads to problems obviously. How can I ignore *doubled doublequotes* wihtout rewriting the csv file with removed *doubled doublequotes*?

Comment: What about reading it into a buffer and stripping it of, without rewriting it out and using that as your csv input?

Comment: I thought there is a more elegant solution.

Comment: You can probably override a dialect's setting to describe your "malformatted"csv, but it's not clean and data should be converted to a standard form.